# How to parse xml in this format

Tags: iphone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

How to parse it?

Comment: Please, use the search field to find one of the many fine answers right here on SO. Similar questions have been asked umpteen times. This is not a "please do my homework" site.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the XML file I suggest to use [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html). It's really easy to use and it's fast. And as far as I got your question, the structure is always the same.

Sandro Meier